# How is react-router being created when using contextTypes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've got `react-router` 4.0.0-alpha.4 installed in my React project, which is a tutorial that I'm following, and I'm having a really difficult time understanding how it's being called in `StorePicker.jsx`

`App.jsx`

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { render } from 'react-dom'; 
import './css/style.css'; 

import {BrowserRouter, Match, Miss} from 'react-router';

import StorePicker from './components/StorePicker';
import App from './components/App';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound';

const Root = () => {
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Match exactly pattern="/" component={StorePicker}/>
                <Match pattern="/store/:storeId" component={App}/>
                <Miss component={NotFound}/>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

render(<Root/>, document.querySelector('#main'));
```

So towards the end in `StorePicker.jsx` I create a `contextTypes` property on the `StorePicker` object. I then set the value equal to `{ router: React.PropTypes.object }`. `React.PropTypes.object` has nothing to do with the router though.

But in `goToStore(event)` all of a sudden the `router` object is available in `this.context.router`.

1. Where did this come from? Is it because the word `router` is a special keyword when I use it in `contextTypes`, and `React.PropTypes.object` somehow knows to fetch the router object as a result and add it to `this.context`?
2. Why is this tutorial even telling me to use this pattern? According to the React docs, `context` should be avoided: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html
3. Is there a better way to do this?

`StorePicker.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { getFunName } from '../helpers.js'

class StorePicker extends React.Component{

    goToStore(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const storeId = "1234";
        this.context.router.transitionTo(`/store/${storeId}`);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <button onClick={(e) => this.goToStore(e)}>CLICK ME</button>
        )
    }
};

StorePicker.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
}

export default StorePicker;
```

The code from this tutorial works, but I have no idea why it's working.

Comment: You'll notice that I already linked to the docs in my question. So it should probably be obvious that telling me the answers are in something that I've already linked to isn't going to get me anywhere. I'm having a hard time understanding the docs. Forgive me for being dumb.

Comment: I was able to find a much, MUCH better resource than the official docs that explains `context` and `contextTypes` in greater detail and clarity: https://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2017/02/context-in-reactjs-applications/

Answer (score 0):

3.Is there a better way to do this? :

You should not use context. It seems you only require to redirect to an url (whose value depends on the text box) when the form submits.

In React, you can use [react routers](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic).

Here's some more examples: [StackOverflow: programmatically-navigate-using-react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Or in Javascript, if you just have to redirect to an url location you can simply use 'window.location' function as follows:

```
goToStore(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const storeId = this.storeInput.value;
    window.location.assign(`/store/${storeId}`)
  }
```

However, you may not want to use second option as Javascript renders whole dom and then there's no advantage of using React  then.